# The container for Google Tag Manager is setting up late in the ios app

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

The container for Google Tag Manager is instantiated in this function, as iOS controls the main thread so this container is setup late and googleTagContainer returns nil once the second function is called :

```
-(void)containerAvailable:(TAGContainer *)container {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //Register custom function call tag or variable handler here if necessary

        [self setGoogleTagContainer:container];

    }); 
}
```

Once the following function is called the container isn't set up yet so it escapes the if statement and looses some tracking data.

```
-(void)trackScreen:(NSString *)screen section:(NSString *)section location:(TWNLocation *)location additionalData:(NSDictionary *)data {

    [super trackScreen:screen section:section location:location additionalData:data];

    //2016.1.8 Google Analytics

    if ([self googleTagContainer] != nil) {

        NSDictionary *googleTrackData = [self googleScreenDataForOmnitureScreen:screen section:section location:location data:data];

        if (googleTrackData != nil) {

            [self submitGoogleTrackingData:googleTrackData];

        } else {

            DMLogDebug(DebugLogTypeTracking, @"Google Analytics tracking data not available for screen: %@, section: %@", screen, section);
        }

    } //end if valid tag

}
```

Is there any way to call this function after the Google container becomes available or any way to save data and send the tracking data after the process of setting up the container gets finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Tag Manager's 3.15 SDK doesn't support this directly, but you can certainly put together a façade that allows you to push tracking data to an intermediate queue, and then flush that queue when containerAvailable is called.

Assuming you have a utility class which loads your container, and has an NSMutableDictionary called `queuedEvents`, and a dispatch queue `_emitQueue` , you might have a method like:

```
- (void)pushDataLayerUpdate:(NSDictionary*)update {
  if (self.container) {
    dispatch_async(_emitQueue, ^{
      [_tagManager.dataLayer push:update];
    });
  } else {
    // The container is not loaded, queue the block.
    [_queuedEvents addObject:update];
  }
}
```

When the container loads, you would flush queuedEvents like so:

```
-(void)containerAvailable:(TAGContainer *)container {
  // dispatch any pending events in the background.
  dispatch_async(_emitQueue, ^{
    self.container = container;
    TAGDataLayer *dataLayer = _tagManager.dataLayer;
    for (NSDictionary *update in _queuedEvents) {
      [dataLayer push:update];
    }
    [_queuedEvents removeAllObjects];
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric!!! your solution worked like a charm, the only thing I defined queuedEvents as a NSMutabaleArray

Comment: I didn't use the _emitQueue but in the containerAvailable method I created dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); instead.